# Convert date from yyyy-mm-dd to dd month_name year

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, date-format

I have stored date in MySQL in the format yyyy-mm-dd and I wish to display it on the form like

ddMMMMyyyy

How can I do that

Comment: Did you try any code ?

Comment: @MahmoodRehman:
I tried
<?php echo convert($row['upload_date'],$row['upload_date'],112);?>

But gave error saying call to undefined function convert()

I got this code in one of the forums here

Comment: pleas look at the `Date()` and `DateTime()` on `php.net`.

Comment: Convert isnt even a php function ...

Answer (score 1):

Use [DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

```
select date_format(date_column, '%d %M %Y')
from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),GETDATE(),106)
```